# Larastan Call to an undefined method UserModel::merge()

Tags: php, laravel, phpstan

Larastan complain about the following code:

```
$update = $request->all();

/** @var UserModel $user */
$user = UserModel::where('email', $request->get('email'))->get()->first();

$update['name'] = 'foobar';

$user->merge($update);
$user->save();
```

Larastan error:

> Call to an undefined method UserModel::merge()

PhpStorm also gives a warning:

> Method merge() not found

I am not sure what the issue is here

Comment: It's better to ask these questions here https://github.com/nunomaduro/larastan/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge()` is the method of collection, not Model object.

After `get()` method, you got a collection.Applying `first()` to collection, you get the model object. So it has no method `merge()`;

if you want to update the fields, you can try `update()` method:

```php
$user->update($update);
```

or set the attribute:

```php
$user->name = 'foobar';
$user->save();
```